What grammar tense should I use in this case?
I am describing financial data in my paper regarding a company's expectations that were made for a time period that already ended. Therefore, I am curious which grammar tense is the best to use in this case?
For example:

"The car market was estimated at $X billion and was anticipated to
grow at a rate of X% from 2020 to 2023. At the end of this period, it
was expected to reach a projected market value of $X billion."
or
"The car market is estimated at $X billion and is anticipated to
grow at a rate of X% from 2020 to 2023. At the end of this period, it
is expected to reach a projected market value of $X billion."

and

The figures were taken from the 2020 annual report.
or
The figures are taken from the 2020 annual report.


For the first pair,  as all the events from estimation to expectation were in the past, we use the first version, all past tense.
For the second pair, as you are describing the financial data in your paper now, both are taken and were taken are possible.  If the figures are newly taken from the annual report, we could use the present tense; if that was done some time ago (for example, for additional  verifications and so on) we use the past tense.

In 2020 it was correct to use the second sentence, but it is not correct to use it in 2024.

Thanks, @Peter.
If the OP’s has just come across the 2020 annual report and is now taking data from there, are taken should be valid, right?

Very well explained.

Thank you greatly for explaining this to me. I really appreciate it!

@SeowjoohengSingapore, Indeed it is. I am not sure I could justify excluding either of the two alternatives for this statement. After all, it is legitimate to ask either "where is the data from" or "where was the data from", and the answer would be the same.
